# Create a website with React Native Expo or React Native Web

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web

I have a mobile app created with React Native. I wanted to create a website of the app and I was thinking of using expo. I also saw there is an React Native Web.

1. Is expo web the same as react native web
2. Does Expo use React native web

Which tool should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No
2. Yes

If you're already using Expo, you can build for web easily. If you're not using Expo, you can simply use **React Native for Web** directly.

Ref: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/web/